# Scons for FPGA?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, scons, fpga, modelsim

Is there somebody who has used '[Scons](http://www.scons.org/)' as a replacement for '[make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/)' for quite large FPGA projects?
Did it ran out-of-the-box or is there still some hacking to be done for the VHDL or Verilog language?  And what about the integration with Modelsim/ISE/Vivado/Quartus?
Or should I stick to makefiles for a while?

Comment: Yes, I have used SCons for a billion+ gate CPU project.  There is no built in support for any targets, so you have to create your own custom builders.  I'm not sure I would go that route if I reach that fork in the road next time.  I liked putting coding in python and being able to construct different variants of builds using a custom inheritance mechanism for different DUT configurations, but I had to code a lot of trappings around SCons.  If I had to do that again, I might simply forgo using the the SCons engine and launch the jobs to the server farm myself using `subprocess`.